# Plu­ral­iza­tion bug in re­ported badges on Span­ish and Por­tu­guese Stack Over­flow sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, localization, plurals

It looks like you have a lo­cal­iza­tion bug on the Badges
pages on the fully lo­cal­ized ver­sions of Stack Over­flow.
You’ve matched the gen­der but not the num­ber, so your con­cord is wrong: you aren’t ac­count­ing for sin­gu­lar ver­sus plu­ral badge counts.

#### [Por­tu­guese badges](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) error: Too few *s*’s on Plu­rals

[image: Por­tu­guese SO badges page error demonstration]

That “7 con­ce­dida” should read “7 con­ce­dida**s**” for the
plu­ral con­cord de­manded by the num­ber seven because it
means that you have *sete me­da­lhas con­ce­dida**s***. The “1 con­ce­dida”
is cor­rect for the sin­gu­lar case for the num­ber one, so *uma me­da­lha con­ce­dida*.

So here the bug is that you are pre­tend­ing ev­ery­thing is sin­gu­lar, even when you 
have more than one badge. You have to add an *‑s* with more than one, you know. :)

#### [Span­ish badges](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) error: Too many *s*’s on Sin­gu­lars

[image: Span­ish SO badges page error demonstration]

That should read “1 otor­gada” for the sin­gu­lar case of having *una me­da­lla otor­gada*. The plu­ral ver­sions like “90 otorga­das” are fine as they stand for *noventa me­da­llas otorgadas*.

That means that you have **ex­actly the op­po­site prob­lem** on the Span­ish site com­pared with the bug on the Por­tu­guese site: now you are pre­tend­ing
**ev­ery­thing** is plu­ral even when you have only one badge.

Comment: Maybe the translators translated "awarded" once in plural and once in singular (as "awarded" is neutral in English)

Comment: The _otorgada_ in singular is in https://traducir.win/string/3052. I just suggested a change to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed meanwhile:

[image]

---

[image]