# Mul­ti­ple plu­ral­iza­tion bugs on the User Ac­tiv­ity page on (at least) the Span­ish Stack Over­flow site, if not o­thers(?)

Tags: bug, localization, plurals, activity-summary, international-sites

Fol­low­ing up on [yes­ter­day’s some­what re­lated bug re­port](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321315/153355), I have
to­day dis­cov­ered that
the User Ac­tiv­ity page on the Span­ish SO site has var­i­ous bugs in its plu­ral­iza­tion:

[image: ES demo of bug in singular votes cast erroneously plural] [image: ES demo of bug in singular useful reports erroneously plural]

No­tice how I’ve the two red cir­cles are around some­thing that
says there’s only one  of it nu­mer­i­cally (digit 1) but whose
cor­re­spond­ing text, be­ing in the plu­ral, in­di­cates that there
are any­thing *but* one.

When you only have one of them, you cannot use the plural. Those should both be in the sin­gu­lar:

- 1 voto emitido
- 1 reporte útil

I do not check to see whe­ther the edit count ­suf­fers from the same bug,
but I wouldn’t be sur­prised if it did.

## How *does* this hap­pen?

***Very cu­ri­ously***, a quick glance at the cor­re­spond­ing
User Ac­tiv­ity page on the Por­tuguese SO site sug­gests that it does
*not* suf­fer from this bug!

[image: PT demo of okness in singular] [image: PT demo of okness in plural]

It seems that some in­ter­na­tion­al­ized sites have nu­meric bugs, but oth­ers 
do not: how ***does*** that hap­pen?  Isn't the code all the same?  Are
you some­how in­cor­rectly mark­ing things sin­gu­lar-ver­sus-plu­ral?

Are you per­haps crowd­sourc­ing out for just one trans­la­tion
for that slot when you need more than one?

Or could it be that when you do not have both slots filled get stuck de­lib­er­ately
us­ing one that’s nu­mer­i­cally in­ap­pro­pri­ate at times?

Comment: Thank you for the report! Could you please check those strings on Traducir.win? I looked on SOru and everything is fine.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Could you please provide a link to that so I can check it? I forget where it lives.

Comment: The app should live on [traducir.win](https://traducir.win). The key for flags "bd494a943365073fe43dd874c93cc686", for votes (probably) "3c871f5787a2ac522436a205c70874f0".

Comment: I have suggested changes in traducir.win to fix this translation bug in the keys given by @Nicolas

Comment: @fedorqui Thank you! I've imported strings to the DB. Let's see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky plural bug is still there see [one of these profiles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6/supporter) or [one of these profiles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol).